# data corrupted in postgres - right sibling's left-link doesn't match: block 9550 links to 12028 instead of expected 12027 in index "log_attach_id_idx"

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres and we are using it for tests reports, we had an issue with our environment that entered duplicate keys to one of the table and since then we are getting this message when trying to run migration scripts:

> error: migration failed: right sibling's left-link doesn't match: block 9550 links to 12028 instead of expected 12027 in index "log_attach_id_idx" in line 0: UPDATE log SET project_id = (SELECT project_id FROM item_project WHERE item_project.item_id=log.item_id LIMIT 1); (details: pq: right sibling's left-link doesn't match: block 9550 links to 12028 instead of expected 12027 in index "log_attach_id_idx")

I tried to run pg_dump and got this error:

> pg_dump: error: query was: SELECT pg_catalog.pg_get_viewdef('457544'::pg_catalog.oid) AS viewdef
> pg_dumpall: error: pg_dump failed on database "reportportal", exiting

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

Restore your backup, and research what parameters you changed and what you did to end up with data corruption in the first place.